# Dialogflow access roles: Deploying credentials with JS client

Tags: dialogflow-es

I created a Dialogflow service account and assigned it the role of **Dialogflow API Client** (i.e. can call all methods on sessions and conversations resources as well as their descendants). I also created a (JSON) key. 
Are there any risks associated with deploying this key as part of my client?

From what I understand, the role is read-only for everything else (i.e. Basically the client can create sessions and query intentens, and that's it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploying this key along with your code to a production server should be fine. However, keep in mind that you should NOT add this file to your Github / Bitbucket repository. Yes, this is read-only but someone could, in theory, spam your Dialogflow agent which would result in you reaching your Dialogflow API quota.

Hope this helps.